# Harmless pranks there for the command line?

Tags: scripts

Seeking harmless pranks or April fools for Ubuntu (one-liners), with which I can bring my colleagues laugh. However, it should not damage the system.

To broad, ok…

1. Only shell scripts
2. With a maximum length of 42 (The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything.)

Comment: https://github.com/keroserene/rickrollrc

Comment: Close voters, give me a chance. =)

Comment: my own contribution [How to display random jokes from www.icndb.com in your terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/527448/how-to-display-random-jokes-from-www-icndb-com-in-your-terminal)

Comment: What Tim said, however personally I'm fine with this question and I'd like it to stay open, so I won't vote to close. What happened to Paranoid Panda today IMO is a good idea to use as a prank: http://askubuntu.com/questions/642349/when-run-cat-says-hello-nothing-to-see-here-move-along

Comment: Also the old-fashioned `chsh -s /bin/false user`

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/232/18237

Comment: `telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl` to watch Star Wars :D I like this one.

Comment: No doubt a sympathetic question, but also no doubt one with a million possible answers, and more a contest on who is the funniest than about solving a technical problem. This simply isn't the place for that.

Comment: is this a coding puzzle? for [codegolf.se]

Comment: type `yes I Love Linux` and press Enter.

Comment: Fork Bomb `:(){ :|:& }:` multiplies itself till all the system resource is utilized and the system hangs... Really nasty and risky one but tricky

Comment: really funny one and catchy `sudo apt-get insatll bb` then type `bb` and follow the outputs ;)

Comment: Alias `cat` to `echo "Never gonna give you up, never gonna let you down . .  ."` . I think @ParanoidPanda will appreciate the joke ;)

Comment: @JoKeR Explain how to stop that music please!

Comment: @JoKeR Ok nevermind, the window closed but I didn't notice the process was still running in the background

Comment: @kos I just pressed Ctrl+C ;) or closing also works.

Comment: Not sure we need a whole new tag for "Humor" as I don't see how it's applying to other questions or whether it even needs to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most classic

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/false user
```

or

```
sudo chsh -s /usr/sbin/nologin user
```

The first one will set `user`'s login shell to `/bin/false`, which is an executable which always returns `false`, effectively cutting the user out of his account;

The second one will set `user`'s login shell to `/usr/sbin/nologin`, which is an executable which will always display a custom message (which is intended to warn the user that he is not authorized to login), configurable in `/etc/nologin.txt`.

You're going to have fun with the second one!

---

If you don't have the target user's password but you have physical access to the machine:

1. Hold <kbd>LSHIFT</kbd> at power-on to boot into `grub`
2. Select the default kernel's recovery mode (e.g. `Ubuntu, with Linux 3.19.0-15-generic (recovery mode)`) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Select `root - Drop to root shell prompt` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Run `mount -o rw,remount /`
5. Run `chsh -s /bin/false user` or `chsh -s /usr/sbin/nologin user`
6. (Optional) If you chose the second method edit `/etc/nologin.txt`in the most profitable way
7. Run `reboot`
8. Enjoy

Comment: The problem is, I don't know the password for my colleagues, but hey, +1 =)

Comment: @A.B. Boot into `grub`, drop to a root shell, `mount -o rw,remount /` and send the command. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 2):

A speak out message:

```
echo 'you are under surveillance' | festival --tts
```

Probably run this on start-up!

Source: This Thread -  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1074772

Comment: In my case I need a `sudo apt-get install festival`

Comment: Yes, we would need to install festival for this :)

Comment: with && it could be?

Comment: Nice! I like this one, with a bit of fantasy and knowledge of your victim is going to be great fun!

Comment: @SanchitKumar `festival --tts <<< "you are under surveillance"`